# Change the text color of PlaceholderText (Windows 8.1 App)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, store, placeholder

I recently discovered the possibility to add a PlaceholderText to a TextBox on Windows 8.1. My problem is its foreground, that is always black.
I would to have the possibility to change the color of the Placeholder's text, but searching on the web I found nothing. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so if we go check out the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710191.aspx) where you'll see the `PlaceholderTextContentPresenter` `ContentControl` that has it's `ForegroundBrush` set to `Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"` which leaves you some options to accomplish your goal.

Depending on whether you want to overwrite it at the instance or globally there's multiple ways you could do it. For globally, just go find the `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush" Color="#AB000000" />` and edit it accordingly. Or name it as a resource at the instance level

However like I said, it's one of those things you can accomplish various ways depending on your situation. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: And what if I want to apply this change only for some textboxes? I created a style, but I made a copy-paste work with the original style, deleting only the first parts of its XAML.

Comment: You could specify the different brush in the resources of that specific control or one of its parents, or put a TemplateBinding on that property in the template to something not already being used like maybe the `Tag` property so you could specify it at the instance level.

Comment: when I use this custom style with ContentControl modified, the delete button breaks, it displays square icon.

Comment: edit: I fixed it modifying `{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}` in `GlyphElement`